# Search based on range on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two rows as shown on my table.

```
   start    end
A)  6        10
B)  2        NULL
C)  26       NULL
```

I have to write a query to list these rows from ranges `$from` and `$to` taken from the user. Like-

Condition 1 - `$from = 3` `$to = 8` - list only A

Condition 2 - `$from = 1` `$to = 8` - list A and also B (as it partially lies within the range)

Condition 3 - `$from = 1` `$to = 30` - list all 3 rows.

I've tried this in where clause -

```
WHERE ((start >= $from)) AND ((end <= $to) OR end IS NULL)
```

But it incorrectly results row C for Condition 1.

Any hints please. Thanks.

Comment: It giving you correct result. As you added in `((start >= $from)) AND ((end <= $to) OR end IS NULL)` `end IS NULL` with OR. so your 2nd condition for 3rd row is also true.

Comment: yes, so wanted to modify this where clause to give correct result as per the conditions

Comment: you want a single query to cover above three condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify WHERE clause the other way round something like -

```
WHERE ((end >= $from  AND start <= $to ) OR 
       (start BETWEEN $from AND $to AND end IS NULL) )
```

Seems to satisfy all your 3 listed conditions with their required outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks something like this:

```
WHERE (start >= 3) AND ((end <= 8) OR (end = NULL))
```

Since the first statement in the AND part is false, it checks the second. The out put is:

```
WHERE (start >= 3) AND (end = NULL)
```

And because C has start larger than 3 AND end = NULL it gets selected

It should work if you drop, or rewrite the NULL part och the WHERE clause.

Update:
If you want to ignore the NULL values, then depending on database one of these will work.

```
WHERE (start >= 3) AND ((end <= 8) AND (end <> NULL))
WHERE (start >= 3) AND ((end <= 8) AND (end != NULL))
WHERE (start >= 3) AND ((end <= 8) AND (end IS NOT NULL))
```

Update 2:
The last parentheses are not needed anymore, giving:

```
WHERE (start >= 3) AND (end <= 8) AND (end <> NULL)
```

Comment: what rewriting can i include ?

Comment: the update will fail for 2nd Condition as I want to include null values

Comment: Well.. your query (#1) asks for a start value greater than 3 and an end value smaller than 8 OR NULL. C fits that criteria. You should get A and C.

Condition 2 should only list B since end in A is neither NULL nor smaller than 8.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you could use:

```
WHERE (start BETWEEN $from AND $to) or (end BETWEEN $from AND $to) or (start >= $from AND end == NULL)
```

Comment: this will result row C for Conditon 1 I guess as last `(start >= $from AND end == NULL)` will evaluate to true for row C

Answer (score 0):

$ WHERE (start >= 3) AND ((end <= 8) OR (end = NULL))

Thnk you ccgen.xyz my frnd